# how to print only Difference in two files using NR=FNR?

Tags: shell, awk, perl, solaris

we have to print the old entries only Delta(Difference) in File-1 and File-2. newly added enties in files-1 no need to print.

on my unix server everyday new report is extracted from system which is later on compared with yesterday’s report.

The newly added lines in Current day report are printed by separate logic, which works perfectly.

Now My requirement is to identify the fields(for $2 check modified $4) those are updated in today’s report after comparing with yesterday’s report. So logic should run to check $2 line by line to find out $4 updated fields from File1 and print the same.

I have NR=FNR logic to do so, but its not working for below case

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F'!' 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4];next} !a[$2,$4]++ || NR==FNR{++a[$4];hold} a[$4]++' file-1 file-2
```

however this new logic has been getting failed for below fields combination,

file-New

```
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 35!
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
8! J9BB-50! LHW! 22!
8! J9BB-50! LHW! 22!
7! test3! test3! 8!
7! test3! test3! 8!
7! JWZZ-50! LHN! 15!
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
8! J9BB-50! LHW! 21!
```

File-Old

```
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
8! J9BB-50! LHW! 22!
8! J9BB-50! LHW! 22!
7! test3! test3! 8!
7! test3! test3! 8!
7! JWZZ-50! LHN! 14!
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
8! J9BB-50! LHW! 21!
```

with new command for compare and print. below logic fail to print expected result,

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F'!' 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4];next} !a[$2,$4]++ || NR==FNR{++a[$4];hold} a[$4]++' File-New File-Old
```

this command is unnecessarily printing the lines

```
8! J9BB-50! LHW! 22! 
7! test3! test3! 8!
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
```

Current Result,

```
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
8! J9BB-50! LHW! 22!
7! test3! test3! 8!
7! JWZZ-50! LHN! 14! 
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
```

Expected Result:

```
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
7! JWZZ-50! LHN! 14!
```

Without lines 2, 3 & 5 from the current result

we have to print the updated File-Old fields(for $2 check modified $4) those are updated in today’s new report. so The logic has to become search $2 from File-Old in File-new if $2 was present in File-New then compared respective $4 values, if $4 is updated then print that line of File-Old.

can anyone please suggest the changes/new logic to get Expected output. if its not possible by using NR=FNR then how can we get it by using shell/perl script?

Comment: It's not very clear the question. Which are the newly added entries ? do you want to print the diff of the files (then why not use `diff`) ?

Comment: Your code is obviously wrong. While reading the first file, you use `FNR` as an array subscript. While reading the second file, you only use two array subscripts. As a result, entries from the first file are not considered.

Comment: there is also a `comm` utility which can print lines only in file1, only in file2 or in both.

Comment: It look to me that removing test3 lines, make **7! JWZZ-50! LHN! 14! 
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34! ** a new entry. You need a formal definition of "new entry".

Comment: @Archemar the `comm` utility requires files that are sorted in ascending order according to its current locale

Answer (score 1):

```
diff file_old file_new |grep '< ' |awk -F'<' '{print $2}'

7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
7! JWZZ-50! LHN! 14!
```

Comment: You can simplify the `grep | awk` pipeline to `awk -F'^> ' 'NF>1 {print $2}`. This also handles lines containing embedded `> ` sequences

Answer (score 0):

I would read in File-2, then look for lines in File-1 that are not in the array. Keep in mind that awk uses the `SUBSEP` variable to join strings in an array index:

```
awk -F'!' 'NR == FNR {f2[$2,$4]; next}  !($2 SUBSEP $4 in f2)' File-2 File-1
```

produces

```
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 35! 
7! test3! test3! 8 
7! test3! test3! 8 
7! JWZZ-50! LHN! 15!
```

Comment: --> I was looking for different output than what you have suggested,
on my unix server everyday new report is extracted from system which is later on compared with yesterday’s report. The newly added lines in Current day report are printed by separate logic, which works perfectly. 
Now My requirement is to identify the fields(for $2 check modified $4) those are updated in today’s report after comparing with yesterday’s report. So logic should run to check $2 line by line to find out $4 updated fields from File1 and print the same. can you suggest improvement.

Comment: Your question should have contained all those requirements, don't you think? The logic has to become "if ($2 was seen in File-2) and ($2,$4 was NOT seen in File-2) then print the line". Implementation left as an exercise

Comment: I made correction in my question could you please take a look now and suggest improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` doing a linewise comparison on fields `$2` and `$4`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f[NR]=$2$4; next}f[FNR]!=$2$4{print }' file1 file2
```

Output

```
7! J9AA-50! LHR! 34!
7! JWZZ-50! LHN! 14!
```